# DateTime.Kind is not returned in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datetime

When dealing with `DateTime` objects with WCF, returned `DateTime` objects are missing the `Kind` property, it will always be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` even if I change it manually before returning it!

I did this in the WCF side:

```
dateFrom = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateFrom , DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

still, it is sent as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` to the client...

Client is WinForm application, server is WCF hosted in IIS.

P.S. I am aware of the `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` method but that's not what I need.

Comment: Where is the request coming from? How are **they** sending the date?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Winform client, server is WCF hosted in IIS.

Comment: And **how** is the Winform client passing the date? Is it including the offset?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud The winform is passing the date normally. I manipulate the received DateTimes before saving them to save them with no time.. the problem is returning them.. it is always returned with no DateTimeKind even if I manually specify it.

Comment: When you say `save them with no time` do you mean save them as UTC or that you save every date with a time of midnight?

Answer (score 5):

You can find the solution in this question:

[Roundtrip XML Serialization of DateTime and xsd:date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297506/roundtrip-xml-serialization-of-datetime-and-xsddate)

> There are different behaviors for handling Date, Time and DateTime
>   values. For DateTime values, if XmlDateTimeSerializationMode is not
>   Local the information about the kind (UTC, Local or Unspecified) is
>   preserved. This is also true while deserializing. However, for Date
>   and Time, they are always serialized out with the same format:
>   (yyyy-MM-dd for Date and HH:mm:ss.fffffff.zzzzzz for Time). So the
>   information about kind is lost on serializing and deserializing.