# Returning the DateTime object as it is using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datetime

I have a `DateTime` object saved in DateTime field in SQL Server. I am dealing with clients from different time zones. I want the DateTime to be returned to the users as it is without being converted to the user's timezone. I have tried setting the `Kind` property of the `DateTime` object to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` so the client's machine does not convert it to the local time but still, somehow it figures out the original timezone and converts it to the local timezone.

For example, if the `DateTime` object is "13DEC2012 00:00" it will return to the client as "13DEC2012 00:00" even if the WCF server timezone is different than the client's timezone.

Comment: What about using DTK.Utc?

Comment: @Lloyd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121343/datetime-kind-is-not-returned-in-wcf

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?

Comment: @ryadavilli it is not the same at all... only the tags are the same. this one is asking about returning datetime as it is. the other one is asking why the datetimekind is not returned...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) for this. That should enable you to represent time as relative to UTC.