# How to control timezone information in XML DateTime serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I'm using an XML api that has a time field. In C# the time is set using this property:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "time")]
public System.DateTime TimeOfDay
{
    get
    {
        return this.timeOfDayField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.timeOfDayField = value;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I set

```
TimeOfDay=new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0);
```

It serializes as

```
<TimeOfDay>14:00:00.0000000-05:00</TimeOfDay>
```

But then when I send it through the API, at the other end it converts it to

```
<TimeOfDay>19:00:00.0000000+00:00</TimeOfDay>
```

but I need it to say

```
<TimeOfDay>14:00:00.0000000+00:00</TimeOfDay>
```

I tried `DateTime.SpecifyKind` but it had no effects. Calling `.ToUniversalTime()` resulted in `<TimeOfDay>19:00:00.0000000-05:00</TimeOfDay>` on my end, and when I run it through the API it adds another five hours to become `<TimeOfDay>00:00:00.0000000+00:00</TimeOfDay>`

How can I set this time so that the result on the other end is `<TimeOfDay>14:00:00.0000000+00:00</TimeOfDay>`. I don't think merely subtracting 5 hours is a good idea because it doesn't account for daylight saving time. I have no control over the API itself--I need C# code that forces it to serialize to `+00` timezone

Comment: The time is correct.  You get exact same time either way.  Computers transmit time using UTC time and computers store the time as a number in UTC.  A conversion is done when a DateTime is output/input to string using the PC TimeZone setting.

Comment: Possibly related or duplicate (agree?): [Roundtrip XML Serialization of DateTime and xsd:date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1297506).  From the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546854): *We have different behaviors for handling Date, Time and DateTime values. ... for Date and Time, they are always serialized out with the same format: (yyyy-MM-dd for Date and HH:mm:ss.fffffff.zzzzzz for Time). So the information about kind is lost on serializing and deserializing.*